# JQuery Calculation on inputs within table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, cordova

I'm developing a simple IOS application in phonegap with jquerymobile. I'm trying to do a simple calculation on an input within a table, but I can't get it too work. It works with the first two inputs, but once I add the jQuery for the third calculation it loses all functionality. 
I have the following HTML

```
                   <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tabledata">Fuel  </td>
                            <td class="tabledata"> Gallonn </td>
                    <td ><input id="a" type="text"></input></td>
                            <td class="tabledata" >138690</td>
                            <td  class="tabledata"><span id="c"></span></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td  class="tabledata" >Electricity</td>
                            <td>KiloWatt-hour (kWH)</td>
                            <td ><input type="text" id="d"></input></td>
                            <td class="tabledata">3,412</td>
                            <td class="tabledata" ><span id="e"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tabledata" >Natural Gas*</td>
                            <td  class="tabledata" >Therm**</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="f"></input></td>
                            <td  class="tabledata" >100,000</td>
                            <td  class="tabledata" ><span id="g"></span></td>

                        </tr>
                       </tbody>
                      </table>
```

and the following script

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
                          function compute() {
                          var a = parseInt($('#a').val(), 10);
                          var c = (a / 138690) * 1000000;
                          var cc = c.toFixed(2);
                          var d = parseInt($('#d').val(), 10);
                          var e = (d / 3412) * 1000000;
                          var ee = e.toFixed(2);
                          var f = parseInt($('#f').val(), 10);
                          var g = (f / 100000) * 1000000;
                          var gg = g.toFxed(2);

                          $('#c').text(cc);
                          $('#e').text(ee);
                          $('#g').text(gg);


                          }

                          $('#a, #d, #f ').change(compute);

                          });

        </script>
```

I'm using jQuery version 1.91.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
var gg = g.toFxed(2);
```

Change that to `.toFixed` and it works for me in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M5LKU/

Comment: I have been looking at this for hours and somehow missed this the entire time. Anyway thanks for your help it works perfectly now.

Comment: Glad it worked. In the future, you may want to look at using a tool like Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools if you have Javascript issues, as they'll alert you to things like this quickly. It'll save you a lot of hair pulling. :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed the letter "i" in "toFixed" function name here:

```
var gg = g.toFxed(2);
```

Comment: @BenDyer .. you where first ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change `g.toFxed(2)` to `g.toFixed(2)`.
Just a typo